# Change column format for each specific header Google Sheet Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

here I present a good challenge.

I need a script that analyzes the cells of a row (header) identify cells containing a specific word (text) using regular expressions (^ \ $ ) and it returns the columns of the cells that meet this condition.

Then, to the obtained columns and one row after the header, apply a format such as font style, size, background color, number format etc ... I have an idea of ​​how to do it but I don't know if I'm going the right way.

I have an idea of ​​how to do it but I don't know if I'm going the right way.

```
var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var DBMxCol = Sheet .getMaxColumns();
var DBHeader = Sheet .getRange(4, 1, 1, DBMxCol).getValues();
var Search = "text_to_search"

// The header range is "A4:Z4"

function DateFormat_Cols() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Header.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(new RegExp("text_search", "gi").exec(DBHeader[0]))}
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of setting the text style, etc. from a text search of a header row.  I collect all of the styling in an array so I can use the multiple sets instead of setting each column seperately.

[image]

Code.gs

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let columns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    let header = sheet.getRange(4,1,1,columns).getValues()[0];
    let range = sheet.getRange(5,1,1,columns);
    let fontSizes = [];
    let fontStyles = [];
    let backgroundColors = [];
    let numberFormats = [];
    header.forEach( column => {
        let change = column.includes("Test");
        fontSizes.push( change ? 12 : 10 );
        fontStyles.push( change ? "bold" : "normal" );
        backgroundColors.push( change ? "#ffff00" : "#ffffff" );
        numberFormats.push( change ? "$0.00" : "0.00" );
      }
    );
    range.setFontSizes([fontSizes]);
    range.setFontStyles([fontStyles]);
    range.setBackgrounds([backgroundColors]);
    range.setNumberFormats([numberFormats]);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

And here is the results

[image]

References

- [Range.setFontSizes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontSizes(Object))
- [Range.setFontStyles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontstylesfontstyles)
- [Range.setBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)
- [Range.setNumberFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats)